# jQuery scope confusion

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jQuery code to find the position of the active link on my top menu navigation:

```
$(document).ready(){
    // Handles the triangle image sprite for the top navigation
$('#topnav a')
    .on({ 

        mouseenter: function() {

            var pos = $("#topnav a.active-top").offset();
            console.log("Top: " + pos.top + " Left: " + pos.left );

            // Get the position of the current hovered "a" element
            var upSprite = $("#upArrow").show(),
                pos = $(this).offset(),
                aWidth = $(this).width(),
                offsetTop = 27, // Adjust this to raise or lower the sprite
                offsetLeft = aWidth / 2; // Centers the element under the link


            upSprite
                .css({
                    "top": pos.top + offsetTop,
                    "left": pos.left + offsetLeft
                });

            //console.log("Top: " + pos.top + " Left: " + pos.left);

        },

        mouseleave: function() {
            // Hide the arrow once the mouse leaves
            $('#upArrow').hide();
        }

    });
}
```

Now when I paste the exact same code outside of this event handler

```
 $(document).ready(function () {        
     var pos = $("#topnav a.active-top").offset();
     console.log("Top: " + pos.top + " Left: " + pos.left );
}
```

I get a complete different value for my pos.left.

As I understand .offset() should give me the position relative the document and unlike .position() which gives me the position relative to the parent container.

Is the code being fed a different type of context when it's in the scope of the .on() event handler? I have tried using $.proxy() to no avail. Any tips are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(document).ready()` fires once the DOM has loaded; but before all images have loaded. You'll find the offset is being changed after you're retrieving the `offset()` by the repainting of the elements due to this.

To fix this you can handle the `$(window).load()` event instead, or continue to retrieve the position inside the click handler (which is what I'd recommend).

Comment: Ah, is there a way to ensure that the offset() is taken after the images are loaded. I was thinking about setting a timeout but that could be very unreliable.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem using $(window).load() which does wait for the images. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to analyze this, because i don't know exactly the element referenced by "#topnav a.active-top" and other elements that (perhaps) modify its position.

I think, there are some processing (image loading, altering the width/height of some elements, etc) after $(document).ready() before $(something).mouseenter().